# Cassandra multiple datacenter unreachable nodes

Tags: cassandra

We have two datacenters of Cassandra one installed on Amazon and the second on our servers connected through VPN. All nodes are working properly, but the local datacenter mark all Amazon DC nodes as down and Amazon DC mark local nodes as down.

Here is the view from local datacenter

```
Datacenter: dca
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
DN  192.168.1.168  146.1 GB   32           ?       08aa50da-c3c7-42bf-820c-89f4379de519  r1
DN  192.168.1.169  149.6 GB   32           ?       7de66517-aa82-4da0-9e5d-4170f135cbd5  r1
DN  192.168.1.170  166.86 GB  32           ?       d756995d-1dfc-466a-bb83-243d7f78badd  r1
DN  192.168.1.171  162.1 GB   32           ?       525e9050-c732-4406-abe8-4fed3d2e86bb  r1
DN  192.168.1.172  181.21 GB  32           ?       7e022e0e-2605-4f28-bc5d-d99a1926bbcc  r1
DN  192.168.1.173  149.8 GB   32           ?       8c7eb22b-9efb-4aa7-be9b-2e9c0a6ff5c5  r1
Datacenter: dcl
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.0.12.2      157.63 GB  32           ?       b3045e13-f42c-4047-88fa-354c522d2f8e  r0
UN  10.0.12.3      135.53 GB  32           ?       2a2eca02-13da-4ce0-926a-86f126c9f747  r0
UN  10.0.12.4      119.9 GB   32           ?       199c8145-fc00-4d97-a395-8658a058fcea  r0
UN  10.0.12.5      132.68 GB  32           ?       7af84cbd-62be-40ee-a0f1-5ebd09855a17  r0
UN  10.0.12.6      134.57 GB  32           ?       91081b02-73f5-4d6a-aa5c-6509e38f93d0  r0
UN  10.0.12.7      114.08 GB  32           ?       9f41e674-82fe-43c2-b392-5aa79f65c17d  r0
UN  10.0.12.8      155.04 GB  32           ?       4509a892-be68-4b69-af7b-c1dd32fe466b  r0
UN  10.0.12.9      149.73 GB  32           ?       8bde10c0-6ebb-402f-b2d1-79f4bcc6b12b  r0
UN  10.0.12.10     100.65 GB  32           ?       51a8ab7a-f898-4d4a-a8fd-87dabbaedd28  r0
```

And this from Amazon DC

```
    Datacenter: dca
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.1.168  154.03 GB  32           ?       08aa50da-c3c7-42bf-820c-89f4379de519  r1
UN  192.168.1.169  157.16 GB  32           ?       7de66517-aa82-4da0-9e5d-4170f135cbd5  r1
UN  192.168.1.170  176.96 GB  32           ?       d756995d-1dfc-466a-bb83-243d7f78badd  r1
UN  192.168.1.171  170.36 GB  32           ?       525e9050-c732-4406-abe8-4fed3d2e86bb  r1
UN  192.168.1.172  190.44 GB  32           ?       7e022e0e-2605-4f28-bc5d-d99a1926bbcc  r1
UN  192.168.1.173  157.84 GB  32           ?       8c7eb22b-9efb-4aa7-be9b-2e9c0a6ff5c5  r1
Datacenter: dcl
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
DN  10.0.12.2      ?          32           ?       b3045e13-f42c-4047-88fa-354c522d2f8e  r0
DN  10.0.12.3      ?          32           ?       2a2eca02-13da-4ce0-926a-86f126c9f747  r0
DN  10.0.12.4      ?          32           ?       199c8145-fc00-4d97-a395-8658a058fcea  r0
DN  10.0.12.5      ?          32           ?       7af84cbd-62be-40ee-a0f1-5ebd09855a17  r0
DN  10.0.12.6      ?          32           ?       91081b02-73f5-4d6a-aa5c-6509e38f93d0  r0
DN  10.0.12.7      ?          32           ?       9f41e674-82fe-43c2-b392-5aa79f65c17d  r0
DN  10.0.12.8      ?          32           ?       4509a892-be68-4b69-af7b-c1dd32fe466b  r0
DN  10.0.12.9      ?          32           ?       8bde10c0-6ebb-402f-b2d1-79f4bcc6b12b  r0
DN  10.0.12.10     ?          32           ?       51a8ab7a-f898-4d4a-a8fd-87dabbaedd28  r0
```

How can I investigate this problem?

Comment: did you set broadcast_address in cassandra.yaml? not to mention, VPN will be difficult to configure - all nodes will have have same IP address I think unless you are doing some nat/pat.

Comment: we didn't set broadcast_address but set listen_address. What is the best way to deploy multiple DCs without VPN?

Comment: there has to be some way for all nodes in your cluster to talk to each other. There are 2 basic ideas - use VPN or give each node a separate external IP address. Either one requires some networking know-how. There are [questions here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=multi+region+cassandra) dealing with similar issues (usually multi-AWS regions but some of the info is good background for your case)

Comment: Thanks @LHWizard for clarification. Regarding the basic question after setting the broadcast_address the problem still exists.

Comment: @M.Almokadem I am facing the same issue :( have you solved this symptom any how?